# How to delete only directories and leave files untouched

Tags: unix, directory, rm

I have hundreds of directories and files in one directory.

What is the best way deleting only directories (no matter if the directories have anything in it or not, just delete them all)

Currently I use `ls -1 -d */`, and record them in a file, and do `sed`, and then run it. It rather long way. I'm looking for better way deleting only directories

Answer (score -19, accepted):

In one line:

```
rm -R `ls -1 -d */`
```

(backquotes)

Comment: Don't pipe the output from `ls`; **especially** not to `rm -r`. It fails when pathnames contain spaces.

Comment: Did not consider the space issue. Will remember that.

Comment: Much more recommended and simple [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668113/13071340)

Answer (score 263):

To delete all directories and subdirectories and leave only files in the working directory, I have found this concise command works for me:

```
rm -r */
```

It makes use of bash wildcard `*/` where star followed by slash will match only directories and subdirectories.

Comment: to skip y/n questions: rm -rf */

Comment: Keep in mind expansion when using this in a script, as asterisks will not expand in quotes. As is, it should work fine. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156534/bash-script-error-with-strings-with-paths-that-have-spaces-and-wildcards

Comment: This is the most highly voted answer but I was testing this out because I am trying to do the same thing but I think this answer just deletes everything and doesn't do what the original question is asking. Take care when using it. Catalint/Jeremy's profile answer does a better job of addressing the question, at least for me. My case was that I have some folders containing files I want to keep but also a bunch of empty junk folders I want to delete so a command based on ```find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d``` is a better option

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s: I upvoted your sentiment, but `rm -rf ./*/` is _also_ only one character away from `rm -rf /*/`

Comment: @poleguy yup, I will delete that comment. For some reason it seems more safe though. I have deleted the comment that suggested `rm -rf ./*/` maybe there's a better way to do this

Comment: @Gi0rgio0s, well, it is more characters so it does give you a bit more time to think about what you're doing. :-) I think the key thing is to recognize the risk, so the comment of being one off from a really bad `rm -rf /` type command is a good comment to leave with the answer.

Comment: There is nothing about "/" flag on the man page of rm. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska It is a bash wildcard and I have added a note to the answer

Comment: "bash wildcard `*/` where star followed by slash will match only directories and subdirectories" – Directories in the current working directory, yes, but *not* subdirectories. Subdirectories will be deleted because of `-r`, not because the wildcard matches them. By default `*` does not match dot files.

Comment: Can check with `ls */` that it returns directories and subdirectories. It is also how bash globstar is described, see [shopt globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) and 
[Pattern-Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

Comment: (1) For an operand being a directory, `ls` will show its content (unless `-d` is used), so you will see names of files (including directories) one level deeper than the operand. E.g. `ls /` does show `etc`. But this is how `ls` works, not `*/`. Check with `echo */`. "[When matching a filename, the slash character must always be matched explicitly by a slash in the pattern, but …](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)" (2) `globstar` is irrelevant because it affects how `**` is interpreted, not `*`. Your answer does not contain `**` (not that it should).

Answer (score 41):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`

then

`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

To add an explanation:

`find` starts in the current directory due to `.` and stays within the current directory only with `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` both set to `1`. `-type d` tells `find` to only match on things that are directories.

`find` also has an `-exec` flag that can pass its results to another function, in this case `rm`. the `'{}' \;` is the way these results are passed. [See this answer for a more complete explanation of what `{}` and `\;` do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085272/5889131)

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 13):

First, run:

```
find /path -d -type d
```

to make sure the output looks sane, then:

```
find /path -d -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

`-type d` looks only for directories, then `-d` makes sure to put child directories before the parent.

Comment: The first command doesn't even work for me.

> find . -d -type -d

find: warning: the -d option is deprecated; please use -depth instead, because the latter is a POSIX-compliant feature.

find: invalid argument -d to -type

Comment: @Anthony you have an extra hyphen in there. It should be `find /path -d -type d`

Comment: awesome answer!

Answer (score 2):

Simple way :-

```
rm -rf `ls -d */`
```

Comment: As others have commented, this won't work if your directory names contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

rm -R $(ls -1 -d */ | grep  .. )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**find** command only (it support file deletion)\

```
find /path -depth -type d -delete
```

**-type d** looks only for directories, then **-depth** makes sure to put child directories before the parent. **-delete** removing filtered files/folders

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, by adding a way to preserve one folder. I execute the command in a subfolder for removing folders in the parent one. It doesn't work for directory names with spaces:

- parent folder => CleanTheSystem
- subfolder_to_be_preserved => Linux
- ```
  file in the subfolder_to_be_preserved => OK_Mackay.txt
  ```
- subfolder_to_delete => Windows
- ```
  too_many_files => ***


   rm -r $(ls -1 -d ../*/ | grep -v Linux);
  ```

  And this works for folder names with spaces:

  ```
   find ../. -type d -name "* *" -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1// /_}"' _ {} \; 2>/dev/null;rm -r $(ls -1 -d ../*/ | grep -v Linux);
  ```

Warning!: Be careful. If you misspell Linux, everything will be erased.