# Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find

Tags: find

Why is there a difference in output between using

```
find . -exec ls '{}' \+
```

and

```
find . -exec ls '{}' \;
```

I got:

```
$ find . -exec ls  \{\} \+
./file1  ./file2

.:
file1  file2  testdir1

./testdir1:
testdir2

./testdir1/testdir2:


$ find . -exec ls  \{\} \;
file1  file2  testdir1
testdir2
./file2
./file1
```

Comment: There is no need to escape the plus (`+`) with a backslash (\\).
The semicolon (`;`) needs to be escaped with a backslash (\\) because
otherwise the shell will read `;` as the end of the `find` command
rather than as the end of the `-exec` attribute, as explained in
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511301).

Answer (score 359, accepted):

This might be best illustrated with an example. Let's say that `find` turns up these files:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

---

Using `-exec` with a semicolon (`find . -exec ls '{}' \;`), will execute

```
ls file1
ls file2
ls file3
```

But if you use a plus sign instead (`find . -exec ls '{}' \+`), as many  filenames as possible are passed as arguments to a single command:

```
ls file1 file2 file3
```

The number of filenames is only limited by the system's maximum command line length. If the command exceeds this length, the command will be called multiple times.

Comment: thanks. this is very useful for wanting to sort the resulting files:

find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -ltr {} \+

Comment: Dumb q: I notice that `+` associated with `-exec` is always escaped, but `+` associated with `-mtime` is not.  Do you know the reason?  I guess it is habit from escaping `;` associated with `-exec`.

Comment: @kevinarpe indeed, I would chalk it up to habit from `;`. Can't imagine it ever being necessary to escape `+`

Answer (score 55):

All of the answers so far are correct. I offer this as a clearer (to me) demonstration of the behaviour that is described using `echo` rather than `ls`:

With a semicolon, the command `echo` is called once per file (or other filesystem object) found:

```
$ find . -name 'test*' -exec echo {} \;
./test.c
./test.cpp
./test.new
./test.php
./test.py
./test.sh
```

With a plus, the command `echo` is called once only. Every file found is passed in as an argument.

```
$ find . -name 'test*' -exec echo {} \+
./test.c ./test.cpp ./test.new ./test.php ./test.py ./test.sh
```

If `find` turns up large numbers of results, you may find that the command being called chokes on the number of arguments.

Comment: Shouldn't find add the results only to a number that makes safe to pass it to the shell? At least is what  `xargs` do... in principle it never chokes for too much arguments.

Comment: @Rmano: I've seen `find` (and `xargs`) on Solaris emit more arguments than could be consumed. The `xargs` (and `find`) in [GNU's findutils`](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=findutils) seem to behave more sensibly, but not everyone uses GNU.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, all POSIX `find` would try to avoid reaching the limit on the number of arguments. And that includes Solaris' (10 at least). Where it may fail is if you do something like `find ... -exec ksh -c 'cmd "$@" "$@"' sh {} +` or `find ... -exec ksh -c 'files="$*" cmd "$@"' sh {} +`, but `find` can't really be blamed for that. Note that GNU `find` was one of the last `find` implementations to support `+` (used to be a pain to port script to GNU systems).

Answer (score 45):

From `man find`:

**-exec command ;**

> Execute command; true if 0 status is returned. All following
>   arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
>   an argument consisting of ';' is encountered. The string '{}'
>   is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere
>   it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
>   where it is alone, as in some versions of find. Both of these
>   constructions might need to be escaped (with a '\') or quoted to
>   protect them from expansion by the shell. See the EXAMPLES sec
>   section for examples of the use of the '-exec' option. **The
>   specified command is run once for each matched file.**
>   The command is executed in the starting directory. There are
>   unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec option;
>   you should use the -execdir option instead.

**-exec command {} +**

> This variant of the -exec option runs the specified command on
>   the selected files, but **the command line is built by appending
>   each selected file name at the end**; the total number of
>   invocations of the command will be much less than the number of
>   matched files. The command line is built in much the same way
>   that xargs builds its command lines. Only one instance of '{}'
>   is allowed within the command. The command is executed in
>   the starting directory.

So, the way I understand it, `\;` executes a separate command for each file found by `find`, whereas `\+` appends the files and executes a single command on all of them. The `\` is an escape character, so it's:

```
ls testdir1; ls testdir2
```

vs

```
ls testdir1 testdir2
```

Doing the above in my shell mirrored the output in your question.

## example of when you would want to use `\+`

Suppose two files, `1.tmp` and `2.tmp`:

**1.tmp:**

```
1
2
3
```

**2.tmp:**

```
0
2
3
```

With `\;`:

```
 find *.tmp -exec diff {} \;
> diff: missing operand after `1.tmp'
> diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
> diff: missing operand after `2.tmp'
> diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

Whereas if you use `\+` (to concatenate the results of `find`):

```
find *.tmp -exec diff {} \+
1c1,3
< 1
---
> 0
> 2
> 30
```

So in this case it's the difference between `diff 1.tmp; diff 2.tmp` and `diff 1.tmp 2.tmp`

There are cases where `\;` is appropriate and `\+` will be necessary. Using `\+` with `rm` is one such instance, where if you are removing a large number of files performance (speed) will be superior to `\;`.

Comment: I can read the man page too. And I did, but I don't think I understand the difference between using ; vs +

Comment: i dont think the -1 was fair, I explained my understaning of the man. I didn't just copy the man and leave. but I have edited my response to include a better example.

Answer (score 16):

`find` has special syntax.  You use the `{}` as they are because they have meaning to find as the pathname of the found file and (most) shells don't interpret them otherwise.  You need the backslash `\;` because the semicolon has meaning to the shell, which eats it up before `find` can get it.  So what `find` wants to see AFTER the shell is done, in the argument list passed to the C program, is

> "-exec", "rm", "{}", ";"

but you need `\;` on the command line to get a semicolon through the shell to the arguments.

You can get away with `\{\}` because the shell-quoted interpretation of `\{\}` is just `{}`.  Similarly, you could use '{}'.

What you *cannot* do is use

```
 -exec 'rm {} ;'
```

because the shell interprets that as *one* argument,

> "-exec", "rm {} ;"

and `rm {} ;` isn't the name of a command.  (At least unless someone is really screwing around.)

**Update**

the difference is between

```
$ ls file1
$ ls file2
```

and

```
$ ls file1 file2
```

The `+` is catenating the names onto a command line.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I am asking whats the difference between using ; vs +

Comment: sorry , but did you read my question or my comment carefully ? May be I need to rephrase it. Why is there a different o/p when I use semicolon with exec in find versus when I use plus with exec in find ?

Comment: This is an excellent explanation for WHY the command is like this, that the accepted answer doesn't cover. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `;` (semicolon) or `+` (plus sign) is how the arguments are passed into find's `-exec`/`-execdir` parameter. For example:

- using **`;` will execute multiple commands** (separately for each argument),

  Example:

  ```
  $ find /etc/rc* -exec echo Arg: {} ';'
  Arg: /etc/rc.common
  Arg: /etc/rc.common~previous
  Arg: /etc/rc.local
  Arg: /etc/rc.netboot
  ```

  > All following arguments to `find` are taken to be arguments to the command.
  >
  > The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed.
- using **`+` will execute the least possible commands** (as the arguments are combined together). It's very similar to how `xargs` command works, so it will use as many arguments per command as possible to avoid exceeding the maximum limit of arguments per line.

  Example:

  ```
  $ find /etc/rc* -exec echo Arg: {} '+'
  Arg: /etc/rc.common /etc/rc.common~previous /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.netboot
  ```

  > The command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end.
  >
  > Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the command.

See also:

- [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)
- [Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find) at SO
- [Simple unix command, what is the {} and \; for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447048/simple-unix-command-what-is-the-and-for) at SO
- [What is meaning of {} + in find's -exec command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195939/21471) at Unix

Answer (score -5):

we were trying to find file for housekeeping.

find . -exec echo {} \; command ran over night in the end no result.

find . -exec echo {} \ + have results and only took a few hours.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how those two ways work and how the results produced by them differ.