# List files over a specific size in current directory and all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command

How can I display all files greater than 10k bytes in my current directory and it's subdirectories.

Tried `ls -size +10k` but that didn't work.

Comment: could you please expand on this question, or at least explain why the two solutions that were posted -- and work, are not appropriate to your assignment. (edit: added please)

Comment: `ls` doesn't have any options to filter output by size. It does have a `--size` option (with no arguments) which prints the size of each file in blocks. By the way, `-size +10k` seems like a syntax that is used with `find`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`find . -size +10k -exec ls -lh {} \+`

the first part of this is identical to @sputnicks answer, and sucesffully finds all files in the directory over 10k (don't confuse k with K), my addition, the second part then executes `ls -lh` or ls that lists(-l) the files by human readable size(-h). negate the h if you prefer. of course the `{}` is the file itself, and the `\+` is simply an alternative to `\;`

which in practice `\;` would repeat or:

`ls -l found.file; ls -l found.file.2; ls -l found.file.3`

where `\+` display it as one statement or:

`ls -l found.file found.file.2  found.file.3`

more on [\; vs +](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085192/638649) with `find`

Additionaly, you may want the listing ordered by size. Which is relatively easy to accomplish. I would at the `-s` option to `ls`, so `ls -ls` and then pipe it to `sort -n` to sort numerically

which would become:

`find . -size +10k -exec ls -ls {} \+ | sort -n`

or in reverse order add an -r :

`find . -size +10k -exec ls -ls {} \+ | sort -nr`

finally, your title says find **biggest** file in directory. You can do that by then piping the code to `tail`

`find . -size +10k -exec ls -ls {} \+ | sort -n | tail -1` 
would find you the largest file in the directory and its sub directories.

note you could also sort files by size by using -S, and negate the need for sort. but to find the largest file you would need to use head so

`find . -size +10k -exec ls -lS {} \+ | head -1`

the benefit of doing it with -S and not `sort` is one, you don't have to type `sort -n` and two you can also use `-h` the human readable size option. which is one of my favorite to use, but is not available with older versisions of `ls`, for example we have an old centOs 4 server at work that doesn't have `-h`

Comment: i tried this on a directory w/o subdirectories and it worked flawlessly. let me try this on a different directory. h/o -- `find` is what you are after, btw.

Comment: ok, I tried it on a different directory. this is what you are after. Can you explain why this is most definitely not this?

Comment: It's because in this assignment we're supposed to input a command. If the command is correct, I get taken to the next section of the assignment.

Comment: Actually this answer is correct. I forgot we covered the find command in this course so we're allowed to use it. Answer was `find . -size +10k`. Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I really really appreciate it.

Comment: this answer is confusing because `find . -size +10k -exec ls -lh {} \+` returns all files not just the ones that are over 10k

Comment: @Ereli That is not the case. Using `find` (GNU findutils) 4.6.0 it functions as intended. Only files > 10k are returned.

Comment: @matchew well, don't upgrade to `4.7.0-git` because it doesn't work. on 4.7.0 I see directories, 0 bytes files, symbolic links and files that are clearly smaller than 10k.

Comment: @Ereli, Sorry its not working for you. As far as I know this is the proper way to do it. Several other answers below reaffirm this as the solution. might it work with `\;` and not `\+`. Could the meaning of `\+` be different in newer versions of `find`? It was a relatively recent addition 5.5 years ago when this question was answered.

Comment: I tried to dig in the `find` source code to see what was changed between 4.6 and 4.7 but couldn't find a good reason for this change in behavior.

Comment: you can reproduce this by running `docker run -i -t ubuntu:bionic sh -c "find . -size +10k -exec ls -lh {} \+"`

Comment: What shell is `sh` linked to? I am using `bash`.

 does it work when appended with `\;` instead of `\+`? Or perhaps just `find . -size +10k -ls` ?

Comment: It is even better when piped with sort like `$ find . -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \; | sort -k 5`

Answer (score 16):

Try doing this:

```
find . -size +10k -ls
```

And if you want to use the binary `ls` :

```
find . -size +10k -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: I want to display them with ls not find. `ls -l . -size +10k` did not work.

Comment: Still didn't work, this is for an assignment. "Your current directory is dir. Display all the files within dir (and it's subdirectories) that are larger than 10k bytes."

Comment: I don't get you. What I propose is exactly what you asked.

Comment: I agree, sputnick, what could he be after. +1 to you as my answer is a modification of your own. I have never used find with the -ls option before, I often find myself using `find` with size or mtime  though.

Comment: The OP has since clearly stated that this is homework and part of the homework is to use ls

Comment: Added a ls binary version in my post.

Answer (score 9):

I realize the assignment is likely long over. For anyone else:

You are overcomplicating.

```
find . -size +10k
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll add to @matchew answer (not enough karma points to comment):

```
find . -size +10k -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec ls -lh {} \; > myLogFile.txt
```

-type f :specify regular file type

-maxdepth 1 :make sure it only find files in the current directory

Comment: (fwiw, we call it "reputation", not "karma". This ain't reddit)

Answer (score 3):

You may use [ls](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) like that:

```
ls -lR | egrep -v '^d' | awk '$5>10240{print}'
```

Explanation:

```
ls -lR         # list recursivly
egrep -v '^d'  # only print lines which do not start with a 'd'. (files)
```

only print lines where the fifth column (size) is greater that 10240 bytes:

```
awk '$5>10240{print}'
```