# How to use ls, grep, and wc to produce a list of all ﬁles in the /usr/bin directory that are at least 10,000,000 bytes in size?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm wondering what command that I need to use on PuTTY to get this result.

Comment: Why those three and what have you done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files over a specific size in current directory and all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282786/list-files-over-a-specific-size-in-current-directory-and-all-subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

That can be done directly with `find`:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -size +9999999c
```

`+` matches files larger than the given size. `-` is less than.

The `c` unit is for bytes. You can also use `k` for kilobytes, `M` for megabytes, and `G` for gigabytes.

Comment: Is there any way that I would be able to get this by using ls, grep and wc?

Comment: It is possible though, because those are the instructions for one of my assignments.

Comment: You could also mow your lawn with a pair of tweezers, but why? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about wc and grep but you can create script that will help using below command.

## ls -lh /usr/bin | awk '{print $5,$9}'

it will post your output like this: 
1.4K anaconda-ks.cfg
17M book1
39M Book2
52 Book3
26M Book4

After that you can script that will help you to filter out [Statement] size with filename.