# Syntax error when using find and sh -c

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, find, sh

When I run this command in Terminal:

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec sh -c "file {} | egrep -o '^.*\d+,'" \;
```

I get this error if a filename contains parentheses:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `file ./(terrible filename).png | egrep -o '^.*\d+,''
```

I know it has something to do with the `sh -c`, but I don't know how to fix it, thanks.

> ./(terrible filename).png: PNG image data, 512 x 512,
>   `// trying to get this result`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically pasting the file name into `sh -c '...'` without any quoting.  The string inside `sh -c` *after* the substitutions made by `find` needs to be valid `sh` syntax, which means there can be no unquoted single quotes, parentheses, etc.

A more robust approach is to use `-exec file {}` and pass all the output from `find` to `egrep`.

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec file {} \; | egrep -o '^.*\d+,'
```

The placeholder token `{}` gets replaced by `find` with the filename currently being processed.  When it is a lone token, `find` can pass in any file name at all; but if you interpolate it into a longer string, such as a shell command, you will need to ensure that any necessary quoting etc. is added somehow.  That's messy, so usually you will want to find a solution where you don't need to do that.

(As pointed out in comments to the other answer, `-exec sh -c 'file "$1"' _ {} \;` is another way to accomplish that; this generalizes to arbitrarily complex shell commands.  If your `find` supports [`exec {} \+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find) you want to add a simple loop: `-exec sh 'for f; do file "$f"; done' _ {} \+` -- incidentally, the `_` is a dummy placeholder for `$0`.)

Comment: I tried something similar earlier, but I got the `{} \; |` part wrong where you got it right - thank you! one quick question - what is the difference between using `{} +;` and `{} \;`

Comment: The former is more efficient but not supported everywhere; it is a fairly recent addition (by glacial Debian / OSX standards).

Answer (score 0):

Are there parentheses in the file names? This might help:

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec sh -c "file '{}' | egrep -o '^.*\d+,'" \;
```

Comment: facepalm! it's always the small things! thank you! :D

Comment: Still not safe against filenames with single quotes. Use `-exec sh -c 'file "$1" | blah blah' -- {}` instead.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thanks, this is a valuable hint!

Comment: @4ae1e1: I get another error when i use it that way... `file -C -m magicfiles, Try \`file --help' for more information.`

Comment: @4ae1e1: Thanks,  I just saw the update; No error this time, but it didn't find the file either...

Comment: @CocoaPuffs I was typing without thinking... Anyway, the idea is there. Not sure why you're getting the strange error. What if you just do `sh -c 'file "$1" | blah blah' -- insert_terrible_name_here`?

Comment: @4ae1e1: This didn't work: `echo "(terrible filename).png" | sh -c 'file "$1" | egrep "^.*\d+,"'`, but this does `sh -c 'file "(terrible filename).png" | egrep "^.*\d+,"`'. Not sure why it doesn't like the `$1`.

Comment: @CocoaPuffs You're doing it wrong. `$1` is the first positional argument, while you're passing the filename through stdin (`$1` is empty in your case).

Comment: @4ae1e1: even if I do `fnfo=$"(terrible filename).png"` and then `sh -c 'file "$fnfo"'` the result comes up empty... no error though.

Comment: @CocoaPuffs Of course it would behave that way. `fnfo` isn't exported, so `sh` doesn't see it. But why are you doing this? `find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | egrep -o "^.*\\d+,"' -- {}` still doesn't work? (I mean, at this point, the discussion is just theoretical; tripleee's answer is better, and my comment was supposed to fix this answer — not to point out the best solution — to begin with).

Comment: @4ae1e1: ^ that works! thanks for clarifying! one too many somethings for this blonde :) the parts where i'm a bit hazy are the differences in `{} +;`, `{} \;`, `-- {} \;`... somehow i have no idea what those do exactly (terminators i presume) :/

Comment: @4ae1e1: I will try to locate the missing manual for those, since that's another question itself. Anyway, thanks for the enlightenment -- always appreciated {} \; - feliz navidad! :)

Comment: @CocoaPuffs http://linux.die.net/man/1/find. `-- {} \;` isn't a special construct though, I'm just using the standard `-exec command \;`; the `--` is for `sh`, or `{}` will be `$0`, and it's my habit to not use `$0` as it has an obvious special meaning but instead use `--` as a placeholder for `$0` (won't call it reasonable — it's just a personal habit).  See http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh.