# When to use -type d-exec chmod 750 / 640 in docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker, devops

I've started to work with Docker for local development moving from installing everything on my mac to containers.  Looking through a number of projects I regularly see the following shell commands, particularly

```
find /www -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \; \
find /www -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

Firstly, what are they trying to achieve, secondly what do the commands actually mean and lastly why/ when would you want or need to use this?

I recently duplicated and modified another project and found pulling these commands out seemed to make no difference (fair enough it was no longer based on the same base container.... but still).

Any glimmer of enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

## EDITS:

That [handy link in the comments below to explain shell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20%2Fwww%20-type%20d%20-exec%20chmod%20750%20%7B%7D) tells us:
What: find all the folders in `/www` and execute the chmod command, changing the permissions to 750
 - still unsure of 750, and more importantly why you would do this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `find` and `chmod` commands?

Comment: [find /www -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+%2Fwww+-type+d+-exec+chmod+750+{})

Comment: thanks for the awesome link, explain shell is going to be my new best friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands sets all files and directories to be readable and writable by the owner, and readable by the group but the files can not be executed by anyone.

You might want to read up on [unix permissions in a bit more detail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183999) first.

```
find /www -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

Find all files under `/www` and set the user to have `r`ead, `w`rite access (6) and the group to have `r`ead access (4). Other users have no access (0).

```
find /www -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```

Find all directories under `/www` and set the user to have `r`ead, `w`rite and e`x`ecute permissions (7) and the group to have `r`ead and e`x`ecute permissions (5) to those directories. Other users have no permissions (0).

The `\;` after each `find` terminates the `-exec` command and must be escaped when run in a shell so it is not interpreted as a regular `;` which is the end of the shell command. This can also be achieved with a `+` which is easier to read as it doesn't need to be escaped and [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085237/1318694). The efficiency can cause differences in output, if you are relying on the stdout/stderr somewhere else.

[Execute permissions on a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252) mean that a user can change into the directory and access the files inside. As a directory can't be executed in the sense of a executable file, the execute bit was overloaded to mean something else.

The [link Cyrus posted to explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20%2Fwww%20-type%20d%20-exec%20chmod%20750%20%7B%7D) is an excellent tool as well.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer, and great links, appreciate it.

Comment: `-exec` has a mandatory last parameter of either `+` or `;` -- so the semicolon here in the OP's original code wasn't a shell directive, but actually a necessary argument. (The `+` form is far more efficient, behaving like `xargs` in that it combines as many arguments as possible onto each command).