# Linux exec difference in command arguments

Tags: linux

I am not that verse in Linux but what is the difference between these two commands?

I have seen this in a script that I am debugging but I dont know what is the use of the one over the other?

They seem to accomplished the same thing but I just would like to know the difference

```
find . -type f exec chmod 777 {} \;
find . -type f exec chmod 777 {} +
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find

Comment: Ohh so that's how it is. Thanks mate. Closing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find)