# Find all node_modules directories

Tags: linux, node-modules

I am a web developer. I checkout many OSS projects and build them. Node modules are notorious in creating too many small files. I am running out of free iNodes because of that. I want an easy way (in linux) to lookup for all `node_modules` and delete unwanted ones. I am using the below command to list all `node_modules` directory and then delete them manually.

```
find ~/projects -name node_modules -prune
```

Is there a first-class utility that provides better way to manage `node_modules`?

Comment: I don't see the problem - house cleaning of big `node_modules` directories - as being solely addressable by a *find rm* approach.  There's more to it:  is this the root node_modules?  How big is it?  When's the last time it was used?  After closing it with the "jeez, this question is a duplicate of find rm usage", people are **still** left with the question of how to clean up their node_modules and reclaim wasted space.  Vote to reopen, SO will not explode because this one question broke the camel's back.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To find and delete all `node_modules` recursively:

```bash
find . -name "node_modules" -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

Comment: What ending sign "+" do in expression above? I don't see this syntax before. Anyway thank you, command works nice.

Comment: @Bacher the `+` changes how the `rm -rf` is executed. Without the `+` assuming the find output yields `./foo/node_modules` and `./bar/node_modules` two `rm -rf` commands would get run; one for each path; Including the `+` passes the list of directories to a single `rm -rf` command. In the latter case you would see `rm -rf ./foo/node_modules ./bar/node_modules`. For a more detailed explanation check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085237

Comment: Could add `-type d`

Comment: **Mention that this command is to delete `node_modules`, in BOLD LETTERS**