# What is the meaning of `find /someDir/* -exec rm {} \`?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, exec

I understand this command

- deletes all files in `/some/directory/` that are at least 4 days old
- leaves all folders intact (giving errors `cannot remove '.../someDir': Is a directory`).

Could someone explain the syntax of `-exec rm {} \;`?

```
find /some/directory/* -mtime +4 -exec rm {} \;
```

In particular, what is the meaning of  `{}` and `\;`? Is `{} \;` the argument to `-exec`?

Comment: See  https://superuser.com/questions/1072679/bash-what-does-means or https://askubuntu.com/questions/339015/what-does-mean-in-a-linux-command

Comment: if I where you I would change the command like this:

`find /some/directory/* -type f  -mtime +4 -exec rm {} \;` to avoid errors while `rm` tries to delete some directories that would be passed by the `find` command, the `-type f` will force the find command to look only for files!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`{}` is the pathname of the current file

`\;` is the semicolon that terminates the command (`rm` in your case). It must be escaped with the backslash because otherwise, shell will interpret it is the end of the whole `find` command

Answer (score 6):

`{}` fills in the results of the `find` expression. `\` is being used to escape `;` because we want `-exec` to pick it up, but bash itself will pick it up by default.

This question has been answered elsewhere a number of times. For example, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711452/empty-curly-braces-and-semicolon-in-bash).