# Linux: How to replace part of filename with specified character

Tags: linux, find

I want to replace part of filename with specified character.

For example:

```
$ ls
SubNetwork=RNCRAM955E,MeContext=RNCRAM955E_statsfile.xml
```

I want to replace `RNCRAM955E` with `RNCMST954E`

Here comes my expected output.

```
$ ls
SubNetwork=RNCMST954E,MeContext=RNCMST954E_statsfile.xml
```

and below is my code：

```
$ find ./ -name '*.xml' | xargs -i echo mv {} {} | sed 's/RNCRAM955E/RNCMST954E/3g' | sh

mv ./SubNetwork=RNCRAM955E,MeContext=RNCRAM955E_statsfile.xml ./SubNetwork=RNCMST954E,MeContext=RNCMST954E_statsfile.xml
mv ./SubNetwork=RNCRAM955E,MeContext=RNCRAM955E_statsfile.xml ./SubNetwork=RNCMST954E,MeContext=RNCMST954E_statsfile.xml
mv ./SubNetwork=RNCRAM955E,MeContext=RNCRAM955E_statsfile.xml ./SubNetwork=RNCMST954E,MeContext=RNCMST954E_statsfile.xml 
mv ./SubNetwork=RNCRAM955E,MeContext=RNCRAM955E_statsfile.xml ./SubNetwork=RNCMST954E,MeContext=RNCMST954E_statsfile.xml
```

I can't understand what's the code of `3g` exactly mean.

In my opinion:
    Does the `sed s/xx/xx/3g` means replace match pattern from the 3rd one to the end ,and the `sed s/xx/xx/3` means only replace the 3rd match pattern?
    BTW, what's the exactly mean of `|sh`, I think it makes the command after `echo` as a shell executing, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3` means to substitute the 3rd match, and `g` means to substitute all matches. When you use them together it means to substitute all matches starting at the 3rd one.

Piping to `sh` means to execute the output of `sed` as shell commands.

Most Linux distributions have a `rename` command that makes this easier:

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec rename 's/RNCRAM955E/RNCMST954E/' {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly explain, but why I type your command , there was no effect? could you please explain the `+` to me ? and why the `-exec` without end  character `\;`?

Comment: `+` instead if `\;` means to run the command once with all the filenames as arguments, instead of running it separately for each file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: There are different versions of `rename` depending on the Linux distro. Check the man page for your version to see how to use it to do what you want.

Comment: get it . type  `rename RNCRAM955E RNCMST954E *RNCRAM955E*` twice is ok.