# How do I find files to edit and export to the same directory as a different file using Awk and Find in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, awk, find, subdirectory

A stupid question to ask however I don't seem to be able to find the answer through stackoverflow or other googled results. Either this question is too specific or too dumb. I think it's the later one...

I am using `awk` to filter files that are under different subdirectory and I want to output the results under the same subdirectory where the file is located.

I was playing with the find command and was able to `awk` the files in all the subdirectory that matches the pattern.

I `find` files ended with .tsv and then awk the 8th column (values that under -1) and then I output the file use the base of the file name and add .txt

```
for file in $(find $DIR2 -type f -name '*.tsv'); do
awk -F$'\t' '$8 < -1' $(find $DIR2 -type f -name '*.tsv') > $DIR2/$(basename ${file%.*}).txt; done
```

However, I am kind of stuck, not knowing how to output the files under the original subdirectory.

If I use `$DIR2/` it only export under this specific directory and without the `$DIR2/`, it gets exported to the current working directory.

Comment: This is very helpful for understanding the exec {}+ command https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
find "$DIR2" -type f -name '*.tsv' -exec \
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==1{close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/[^.]+$/,"txt",out)} $8 < -1{print > out}' {} +
```

If your `find` doesn't support `+` then replace it with `\;`.

Comment: Thank you - I corrected it to directory. I am going to test your code now!

Comment: It works well in my test directory! Thank you. Could you expand and explain a little what the code mean so that I could learn from it and use it in the future? Thank you. especially the "close(out)" and "{} +" part.

Comment: And I really like your suggestion as it does not involve a for loop.

Comment: You're welcome. I really think it's pretty obvious what the code does though. Did you try looking up `close()` in the awk man page and `{} +` in the find one? `close(out)` is closing the file we just finished writing to and `{} +` represents the list of files that `find` is passing to `awk` in batches.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the close() and awk syntax for enclosing {} - I am looking at them now. Thanks again!

Comment: This post is quite helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find