# read a file and redirect it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Im trying to find a file with x type and store that in a variable. It is working fine when i try to execute manually. If i try the same in a bash script it is displaying `test_count='1` because of this "if" condition is failing.

Please find the code below :-
`

```
usage_backup_dir=/test/usage_backup
DT_FILENAME=$(date +%Y%m%d); 
export DT_FILENAME
test_count=$(find $usage_backup_dir -type f -name "Summary_$DT_FILENAME*.bdm_all_cases.lg.log" -exec cat {} + )
echo $test_count`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command looks weird:

```
find $usage_backup_dir -type f -name "Summary_$DT_FILENAME*.bdm_all_cases.lg.log" -exec cat {} +
```

I would end it as follows:

```
find $usage_backup_dir -type f -name "Summary_$DT_FILENAME*.bdm_all_cases.lg.log" -exec cat {} \;
```

(I've replaced `+` by `\;`)

I know there's some discussion about this ending (backslash or not, semicolon or not) but I'd advise you to have a look there.

Comment: [Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6085156/3282436)

Comment: Same outout it is displaying bkup_count='1

Comment: Did you try adding a backslash before the plus-sign?