# Search multiple strings in one line using regex in nested files/directories and output matched results

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, xargs

For example, if there are files and directories:

```
/tmp/temp_dir/subdir_001/file_001.txt
/tmp/temp_dir/subdir_001/file_002.txt
/tmp/temp_dir/subdir_002/file_003.txt
/tmp/temp_dir/subdir_003/file_004.txt
```

And those have various contents with specific lines that can be found by regex. For example, here is the content of the file `file_001.txt`:

```
abc cba
little boy writes -54321_12345 and goes to street 987
bca acb
little boy writes -12345_54321 and jumps to street 789
cab bac
```

What I'm interested is those lines that are started with `little boy writes`.
I'm using this regex pattern to find important data that I would like to save as output:
`little boy writes (\-\d+\_\d+).*street (\d+)`

How can I search it recursively and output only matched strings? So in output file I would only have this:

```
54321_12345 987
12345_54321 789
```

Comment: Thing about using find and exec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `find` and `sed` should do the trick :

```
find /tmp/temp_dir/ -type f -exec sed -En 's/little boy writes -([0-9]+_[0-9]+).*street ([0-9]+)/\1 \2/p' {} + > output
```

Breakdown :

- `find /tmp/temp_dir/ -type f` : we find every file recursively from the root folder
- `-exec sed '... ' {} +` runs a command on every file found (here `{}` represents the item retrieved by the `find` command, and `+` means the command is executed once againt the final result, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find))
- `sed -En 's/little boy writes -([0-9]+_[0-9]+).*street ([0-9]+)/\1 \2/p'` : we run the pattern you described in your question, using `sed` (`\d` is not a valid sed character class, we use `[0-9]` instead)
- `> output` we redirect the output of this command to a file called `output`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep` combined with `sed`:

```
$ grep '^little boy writes' /tmp/temp_dir/subdir_*/file_*.txt | sed -re 's/^.* -([0-9]+_[0-9]+).*street ([0-9]+)/\1 \2/' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* get the lines with just a recursive `grep`, with or without filenames.

```
grep -r  '^little boy writes' *  # lists source filenames
grep -hr '^little boy writes' *  # does not
```

This reports the whole line, though. Perl pattern matching (`-P`) with `-o` could probably detect the right lines and only return the bits you want, but the pattern would be horrible for most people to understand and maintain, so it's probably worth a second process -

```
grep -hr '^little boy writes' /tmp/temp_dir/subdir_[0-9][0-9][0-9]/file_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt |
  sed -E 's/[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+)/\1 /g'
```

or if you really want to avoid that space at the end,

```
grep -hr '^little boy writes' /tmp/temp_dir/subdir_[0-9][0-9][0-9]/file_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt |
  's/^[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+)[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+$)/\1 \2/'
```

But if you know exactly where those files are well enough for globbing like that, all you need is the sed.

```
sed -En '/^little boy writes/{ s/^[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+)[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+$)/\1 \2/g; p; }' /tmp/temp_dir/subdir_[0-9][0-9][0-9]/file_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
```

If you don't, `grep` and/or `sed` may grind through a lot of data that you could avoid...and maybe your directory structure isn't quite that consistent. In that case, `shopt` will help.

```
shopt -s globstar # let's ** stand for variable depth of subdirectories
sed -En '/^little boy writes/{ s/^[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+)[^0-9_]*([0-9_]+$)/\1 \2/g; p; }' **/file_[0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
```

That should be a lot more efficient (and so faster). It will let the OS pick files that match and hand only those to `sed` for scanning.

This also uses just one instance of `sed`, rather than spawning one for each file with `find` or needing an `xargs`.

Good luck.