# find exec rm: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell

Why "No such file or directory" in example below?
There are workarounds to not get this error, the question is why in this exact example the error is produced.

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF
mkdir -p TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF

find . -iname 'A*' -exec rm -rvf {} \;
removed directory: `./TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory: `./TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory: `./TOP1/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory: `./TOP1/AB/AC'
removed directory: `./TOP1/AB'
find: `./TOP1/AB': No such file or directory
removed directory: `./TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory: `./TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory: `./TOP2/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory: `./TOP2/AB/AC'
removed directory: `./TOP2/AB'
find: `./TOP2/AB': No such file or directory
```

Using `-depth` or `\+` or `-delete` fix this issue:

```
find .        -iname 'A*' -exec rm -rvf {} \+
find . -depth -iname 'A*' -exec rm -rvf {} \;
find . -iname 'A*' -delete
```

Comment: Try manually deleting `./TOP1/AB` followed by `./TOP1/AB/AC`. When you get to `./TOP1/AB/AC` you will also find that there is no such file or directory (because you already deleted it as part of deleting `./TOP1/AB`)

Comment: If using GNU find, use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm ...`

Comment: -delete implies -depth

Comment: @thatotherguy `rm -rf` on non-exiting folder does NOT error out! try `rm -rf somthing-that-does-not-exist` and you don't get `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is in the man page itself: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Also see `\;` vs `+`: [Using semicolon (;) vs plus (+) with exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find)

To understand the whole process better, you can print the files instead of deleting them. Considering the `TOP1` folder for example:

```
find . -iname 'A*' -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Output:

```
./TOP1/AB
./TOP1/AB/AC
./TOP1/AB/AC/AD
./TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE
./TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF
```

What `\;` does is: *Run file on every file in or below the current directory.*
The order is important here, i.e. first the parent folder is treated, and then its child folders are recursively traversed.

On the other hand, this is how `rm -frv` works:

```
rm -frv ./TOP1
```

Output:

```
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC'
removed directory './TOP1/AB'
removed directory './TOP1'
```

So `rm -fr` works practically the other way round than `find`, which is the main cause of the problem here:

`find` together with `\;` first starts with the parent folder `TOP1`, where the folder `TOP1` and its contents will be completely deleted thanks to the part `-exec rm -rvf {} \;`. On the next round `find` then will try to handle the next child folder below, where it apparently first checks (via `stat ./TOP1`), if the base folder still exists, and it only then goes one level deeper. But since `./TOP1` was already deleted in the first round, `stat ./TOP1` will fail, hence the error message.

With the [other parameters available](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for the `find` you can obviously change the default behavior:

- `-depth`: *Process each directory's contents before the (parent) directory itself.  The -delete action also implies -depth.* (i.e. treversing from very bottom to top - just like `rm -fr` does!)
- `-delete`: *Use of -delete automatically turns on the `-depth` option*
- Using `+`: the `-exec rm -rvf {} +` part is executed only once, e.g. `-exec rm -rvf {} +`:

```
rm -frv ./TOP1/AB ./TOP1/AB/AC ./TOP1/AB/AC/AD ./TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE ./TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF
```

Last but not least:
When `rm` is used with the `-fr` parameter, it becomes very "tolerant", so, no error is thrown. It will try to *forcibly* and *recursively* delete everything that is passed to it; and, if it encounters files/directories that do not exist, it will not complain as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation detail of `find`. You'll find the ultimate answer to your question in it's source code.

On Linux another way to understand what is happening behind the scenes is `strace`. I've prepared some interesting output from strace below. You may have a look at the order of the `openat` system calls issues by both find invocations (with and without `-depth`):

```
mkdir -pv TOP{1,2}/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF && strace -o foo find . -depth -iname 'A*' -exec rm -rvf {} \; ; grep openat foo
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC/AD'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC/AD'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC'
removed directory './TOP1/AB'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC'
removed directory './TOP2/AB'
5:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
9:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
28:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
44:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
52:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
60:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
93:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
99:openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
102:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
106:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 4
114:openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
125:openat(5, "TOP1", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
137:openat(7, "AB", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
149:openat(8, "AC", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
161:openat(9, "AD", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
173:openat(10, "AE", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
186:openat(11, "AF", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
223:openat(8, "..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
231:openat(5, "..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
237:openat(6, "TOP2", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
249:openat(7, "AB", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
261:openat(8, "AC", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
273:openat(9, "AD", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
285:openat(10, "AE", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
298:openat(11, "AF", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
332:openat(8, "..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
340:openat(5, "..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6




mkdir -pv TOP{1,2}/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF && strace -o foo find . -iname 'A*' -exec rm -rvf {} \; ; grep openat foo
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC/AD'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC/AD'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE'
mkdir: created directory 'TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory './TOP1/AB/AC'
removed directory './TOP1/AB'
find: ‘./TOP1/AB’: No such file or directory
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE/AF'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC/AD/AE'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC/AD'
removed directory './TOP2/AB/AC'
removed directory './TOP2/AB'
find: ‘./TOP2/AB’: No such file or directory
5:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
9:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
28:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
44:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
52:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
60:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
93:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
99:openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
102:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
106:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 4
114:openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
125:openat(5, "TOP1", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
142:openat(7, "AB", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
143:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
148:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/findutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
149:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/findutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
150:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/findutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
151:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/findutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
154:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
155:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
156:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
157:openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
164:openat(5, "TOP2", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
179:openat(7, "AB", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```